# Making a python library to installable with Conda

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I want to make the pytorch higher library https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/78 installabled with conda.

How does one do it so that anyone can install it with Conda?

Comment: Here is a starting point https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html#building-a-simple-package-with-conda-skeleton-pypi

Comment: I would start with reading the Conda Forge [documentation on Adding a Recipe](https://conda-forge.org/#add_recipe), since that would be where to host if you want it widely available. Since it looks like pure Python with no extra build steps, it should be a straightforward process.